# Remove CSS delcarations with PHP

Tags: php, regex, replace

I'm just wondering how I could remove the CSS delcarations from string in PHP.

What a string looks like?

```
body, html{
    font-family:'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background-color:white;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
body{
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
header{
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
```

What should the result be?

```
body, html{

}
body{

}
header{

}
```

I have

```
$string = 'body, html{ overflow-x:hidden; } body{overflow-y:hidden; } header{ position:relative; z-index:2; }';
```

and need to get

```
$string = 'body, html{} body{} header{}';
```

Comment: Sorry this is both **Too Broad** and **Unclear** at the same time

Comment: Are you trying to edit the CSS in a file, before it gets sent to the browser, or do you mean you want to find a way to ignore the CSS in thes blocks when you get to the browser???

Comment: Add that to your question using the ___edit___ link under the question

Comment: No, just have string $string = 'body, html{ overflow-x:hidden; } body{overflow-y:hidden; } header{ position:relative; z-index:2; }'; and need to get $string = 'body, html{} body{} header{}';

Comment: `$string = 'body, html{} body{} header{}';` seems like it would get the desired result

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly

Comment: You must be joking!

Comment: I just misspelled the question, thanks for the correction.

Comment: Use a css parser like this one: https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser. A naive pattern is unable to deal with edge cases like curly brackets enclosed in a string or a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this regex

```
preg_replace("/\{.*\}/sU", "{}", $input_lines);
```

Comment: if someone can provide an explanation as the downvotes on why this is incorrect that would be helpful

Comment: Here's the thing.  It is correct until you least suspect it and it fails because of a fringe case -- and there are rather a few.  https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser/tree/master/tests/files (as mentioned in comments under the question).  Those of us that love StackOverflow and seek to protect it, know that answers will be viewed and used by countless future researchers.  We have to think broadly about what is right and what could be wrong within a reasonable scope.  This pattern will fail on many fringe cases -- that is why you've been downvoted.  Test: https://regex101.com/r/Gkz61o/2

Comment: i appreciate the response. So if i edit the question to suggest this isn't the correct way to do it and provide a link to a packaged css parser, this would be correct? I just don't understand the incetive to answer directly to a user if the answer will be disregarded. As long as a soultion is provided and the user is happy, others are still able to provide their own solution instead of just downvoting or can by all means edit mine if they are concerned? Leaving a downvote however and not providing any feedback and i can't see is constructive in any way.

Comment: I can sympathize.  Too often am I smacked with no-comment downvotes.  I also want to state that I have not downvoted.  Yes, as a general rule, when I provide a regex method for a case that cannot reliably use regex,  I write a disclaimer which states the instability of my method.  I do what to point out that "_Try This_" answers really grate me on StackOverflow -- they are basically code-only answers which do very little to educate the OP and future researchers.  If you want to run the risk of gaining upvotes, I recommend expanding and explaining your answer.

Comment: appreciate the response. I don't mind constructive feedback, i just don't see how anyone is benefited from a downvote and a lack of explanation.  Now that it has been explained and an example has been shown, i understand it's wrong and i can adjust to a more suitable answer.

Comment: I've tried removing the answer, albeit i can't as it's accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The warnings from others are founded.  As careful as a regex pattern can be designed, it is still vulnerable to fringe cases and character anomalies that will silently break the method.

The following is my most-carefully crafted bandaid solution.  It is using alternatives and recursion in an attempt to safeguard against nested brackets, commented curly braces, and braces that exist inside of quoted substrings.

I am sure that I have not considered all of the possible monkeywrenches, but this is a rabbit hole that I don't wish to spend any more time on.

Code: ([Demo with two sample inputs](https://3v4l.org/5c5TL))

```
echo preg_replace('~(?:\s*/\*.*?\*/\s*)|\{\K(?:\'[^\']*\'|"[^"]*"|/\*.*?\*/|(?:(?R)|[^}]))*~', '', $css);
```

Or have a play with this [Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kgEdbV/1/).

Comment: @Jarek I've refined my regex pattern to better cover some fringe cases.  That said, I must echo that even this careful pattern will be flawed.

Comment: @Jarek Juakali seems to want to delete rather than improve his/her answer but cannot because of the green tick.  If you remove the tick, the answer can be removed.